# How do I iterate over object properties and assign user input to them?

Tags: python, loops, properties

I'm teaching myself python by writing a DnD-style roguelike/dungeon crawler game. I'm basing the character creation and gameplay on the 5E SRD.

I have completed the Roguebasin TCOD tutorial, and the text adventure tutorial by Philip Johnson.

What I'm trying to do is take a value from input and assign it to the appropriate stat, which is I've defined as a property of the character object.

```
class BaseCharacter:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.strength = None
        self.dexterity = None
        self.constitution = None
        self.intelligence = None
        self.wisdom = None


            print("With the standard array, you get these scores to distribute as you see fit: ")
            print("15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8")
            values = [15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8]
            stats = ["strength", "dexterity", "constitution", "intelligence", 
             "wisdom", "charisma"]
               ordered_values = []
            for s in stats:
                print("Which score would you like to assign to {}?"                     
                   .format(s))
                value = input()
                ordered_values.append(value)
                values.remove(int(value))
                print("Remaining values: " + str(list(values)))
```

I've got some of this just so my code compiles and runs for testing. I want to iterate over the list of stats and assign the user input to the corresponding stat:

```
Which score would you like to assign to strength?
15
Remaining values: 14, 13, 12, 10, 8

print(self.strength)
15
```

This seems doable, but so far all I've come up with is to zip the stats and inputs into tuples. I'm drawing a blank on how to actually ensure the correct values are assigned to the correct property.

Comment: You know you can pass those values to the constructor of your class?

Comment: But wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the loop? I originally had `self.s = value`, thinking that would use the current value of s. However Python seems to interpret it as though I'm trying to assign `self.s` as a new property and gives an unresolved name error.

Comment: Never mind. I didn't read further down. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something along these lines. Provide the values for the instance in a constructor. To get those values, I would repeatedly ask for input and map names to values. The `__repr__` method is just for nice printing. Might come in handy later on when displaying the stats.

```
class Dude:
    def __init__(self, strength, dexterity, constitution, ingelligence, wisdom, charisma):
        self.strength = strength
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.constitution = constitution
        self.ingelligence = ingelligence
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.charisma = charisma

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"""Dude:
STR: {self.strength}
DEX: {self.dexterity}
CONST: {self.constitution}
INT: {self.ingelligence}
WISD: {self.wisdom}
CHAR: {self.charisma}
"""


values = [15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8]
stats = ['strength', 'dexterity', 'constitution', 'ingelligence', 'wisdom', 'charisma']

assigned = {}
for stat in stats:
    print('Assigning %s:' % stat)
    print('Values left: %s' % str(values))
    val = int(input('Choose:'))
    assigned[stat] = val
    values.remove(val)

d = Dude(**assigned)
print(d)
```

Sorry for the Python 3, I'm sure you can translate (judging Py2.X from that print without parenthesis in your question)

Comment: Actually I'm using Python 3.7.4, but the tutorials I found were originally designed for older versions. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read the values outside `__init__`, and pass them as arguments to when you instantiate the character. If you want to wrap the interactive session along with instantiation in a single function, make that a class method.

```
import random


class BaseCharacter:
    stats = ["strength", "dexterity", "constitution", "intelligence", "wisdom", "charisma"]
    def __init__(self, s, d, co, i, w, ch):        
        self.strength = s
        self.dexterity = d
        self.constitution = co
        self.intelligence = i
        self.wisdom = w
        self.charisma = ch

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        print("With the standard array, you get these scores to distribute as you see fit: ")
        values = [15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8]
        print(values)
        ordered_values = []
        for s in self.stats:
            print("Which score would you like to assign to {}?".format(s))
            value = input()
            ordered_values.append(value)
            values.remove(int(value))
            print("Remaining values: " + str(list(values)))

        return cls(*ordered_values)

    # To demonstrate the benefit of separating the source of the
    # attributes from the actual instantiation
    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        # Simulate 3d6 for each of the 6 stats
        random_stats = [sum(random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(3))
                         for _ in self.stats]
        return cls(*random_stats)

new_character = BaseCharacter.create()
```

Comment: Actually, ignore my answer, there's a far more simple solution. In your `__init__` function of your class, you assign `self.constitution` to `c`, but in the argument list, it's `co`

Comment: Oops, thanks, forgot to update that after adding the missing charisma argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, just make sure there's no way to abuse it and change the attribute of something not meant to be changed. Here's an example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.example = 'example'

t = Test()
t.example # 'example'
setattr(
    t, # your object (character)
    'example', # this means you're gonna change t.example
    'something else') # new value of t.example
t.example # 'something else'
```

Comment: I think I understand. So using my example, instead of appending it to "ordered values", I would use `setattr(player, s, value)' to take the input I stored in value and assign it to whichever stat it is currently iterating over?